# subsetting a tibble using logical matrix?

Tags: r, tidyr, tibble

I have a logical matrix. How can I use this to subset a tibble and replace the values?

For example:
 if we have a dataframe:

```
dat <- head(iris)[1:3]
dat[dat>3.5] <- 0
dat
```

What if I have a tibble?

```
library(tidyr) # ver 1.0.0
dat <- as_tibble(head(iris)[1:3])
dat[dat>3.5] <- 0 ## DOES NOT WORK. Howto go around this?
```

The error:

```
dat[dat>3.5]
Error: Must use a vector in `[`, not an object of class matrix.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.


rlang::last_error()
<error/rlang_error>
Must use a vector in `[`, not an object of class matrix.
Backtrace:
 1. dat[dat > 3.5]
 2. tibble:::`[.tbl_df`(dat, dat > 3.5)
 3. tibble:::check_names_df(i, x)
```

Comment: It does work for me though. `dat$Sepal.Length#
[1] 0 0 0 0 0 0`. Please include the package versions

Comment: which version of `tidyr`? I am using `1.0.0`, p`ackageVersion("tibble")
[1] ‘2.1.3’`

Comment: I have `packageVersion('tidyr')
[1] ‘1.0.0’
> packageVersion('tibble')
[1] ‘2.99.99.9012’`

Comment: This works for me too.  Is the error being thrown from a fresh session?  No other packages are loaded?

Comment: @MauritsEvers `tibble` version is `2.1.3`

Comment: What does `rlang::last_error()` give?

Comment: @wibeasley tried with a new session. Nothing works. Guess its my R. will have to look for a way to solve this

Comment: @MauritsEvers added that to the question. Guess this is just a problem on my end

Comment: @akrun does `dat[dat>3]` work on your end?

Comment: yes, `dat[dat>3]
[1] 3.5 3.2 3.1`

Comment: @akrun thanks. Guess will have to reinstall my R